# Wordpress horizontal menu appear vertical in IE

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer

My wordpress site working fine with all browser except Internet Explorer. In internet explorer 8, all my menu shows vertical and my original menu is horizontal,

And all bowser like chrome and firefox shows perfect but not IE

Take a look here with IE 8 : http://www.booksofvirtue.com/

css -

```
.main-navigation {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 66.75;
min-height: 45px;
position: relative;
}

ul.nav-menu,
div.nav-menu > ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 15px 0px 0 0;
text-align: right;
}

.nav-menu li {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

.nav-menu li a {
color: #3b3b3d;
display: block;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
line-height: 1;
padding: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu li:hover > a,
.nav-menu li a:hover {
border-bottom: 0px solid #e9e9e9;
}

.nav-menu .sub-menu,
.nav-menu .children {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
box-shadow:0 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
background:#fff;
display: none;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
left: -25px;
color: #3b3b3d;
z-index: 99999;
text-align: left;
}

.nav-menu .sub-menu ul,
.nav-menu .children ul {
border-left: 0;
left: 145px;
top: 0;
}

ul.nav-menu ul a,
.nav-menu ul ul a {
color: #3b3b3d;
margin: 0;
width: 160px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ul.nav-menu ul a:hover, .nav-menu ul ul a:hover {
color: #fff;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
-moz-animation-name: fadeIn;
-o-animation-name: fadeIn;
animation-name: fadeIn;
animation-delay: 0s; /* W3C and Opera */
-moz-animation-delay: 0s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
-ms-animation-fill-mode:both;
-o-animation-fill-mode:both;
animation-fill-mode:both;
-webkit-animation-duration:1s;
-moz-animation-duration:1s;
-ms-animation-duration:1s;
-o-animation-duration:1s;
animation-duration:1s;

}

ul.nav-menu li:hover > ul,
.nav-menu ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
}

.menu-toggle {
display: none;
}
```

and

Header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>

<!--  Basic Page Needs -->
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<title><?php global $page, $paged;
    wp_title( '', true, 'right' );
    ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<!-- Favicon -->
<?php if ( ot_get_option('wpl_favicon') ) { ?>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo ot_get_option('wpl_favicon');  ?    >">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="<?php echo ot_get_option('wpl_favicon');   ?>" />
<?php } ?>

<!-- Mobile Specific Meta -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-   scale=1">

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo(  'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( "comment-reply" ); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>


</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page">

    <!-- Toolbar -->
    <div id="toolbar">
        <div class="container_16">

            <div class="grid_16">


                    <?php
                        if ( has_nav_menu( 'language' ) ) { 
                            wp_nav_menu( array('depth' => '3', 'theme_location' => 'language' ));
                    } ?> 


                <ul class="tb-list">
                    <?php if ( ot_get_option('wpl_phone_number') != "") { ?>
                        <li class="phone"><a href="tel:<?php echo ot_get_option('wpl_phone_number') ?>" ><?php _e('Tel.:', 'wplook'); ?><?php echo ot_get_option('wpl_phone_number') ?></a></li>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ( ot_get_option('wpl_rss_link') != "") { ?>
                        <li class="rss"><a href="<?php echo ot_get_option('wpl_rss_link') ?>"><i class="icon-feed2"></i></a></li>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ( ot_get_option('wpl_contact_page_link') != "") { ?>
                        <li class="contact"><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(ot_get_option('wpl_contact_page_link')); ?>"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></a></li>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ( ot_get_option('wpl_contact_email') != "") { ?>
                        <li class="contact"><a href="mailto:<?php echo ot_get_option('wpl_contact_email'); ?>"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></a></li>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ( ot_get_option('wpl_group_icons') != "off") { ?>

                        <?php $toolbar_share = ot_get_option( 'toolbar_share', array() ); ?>
                        <?php if( $toolbar_share ) : ?>
                            <li class="share"><a href="#"><i class="icon-share"></i></a>
                                <ul class="share-items radius-bottom">
                                    <?php foreach( $toolbar_share as $item ) : ?>
                                        <li class="share-item-<?php echo $item['wpl_share_item_icon']; ?> radius"><a target="_blank" title="<?php echo $item['wpl_share_item_name']; ?>" href="<?php echo $item['wpl_share_item_url']; ?>"><i class="<?php echo $item['wpl_share_item_icon']; ?>"></i></a></li>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php } else { ?>


                        <?php $toolbar_share =   ot_get_option( 'toolbar_share', array() ); ?>
                        <?php if( $toolbar_share ) : ?>
                            <?php foreach( $toolbar_share as $item ) : ?>
                                <li class="share-item-<?php echo $item['wpl_share_item_icon']; ?> mt"><a target="_blank" title="<?php echo $item['wpl_share_item_name']; ?>" href="<?php echo $item['wpl_share_item_url']; ?>"><i class="<?php echo $item['wpl_share_item_icon']; ?>"></i></a></li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ( ot_get_option('wpl_search_form')  == "on") { ?>
                        <li class="search"><a href="#"><i  class="icon-search"></i></a>
                            <ul class="search-items  radius-bottom">
                                <li>
                                    <div  class="search-form">
                                         <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
                                             <div>
                                                 <input type="text" value="<?php _e('Search for...', 'wplook'); ?>" name="s" id="s" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
                                                 <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
                                             </div>
                                         </form>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php if ( ot_get_option('wpl_donete_link')  != "") { ?>
                        <li class="donate"><a href="<?php echo ot_get_option('wpl_donete_link') ?>"><?php _e('Donate', 'wplook'); ?> <i class="icon-heart"></i></a></li>
                    <?php } ?>

                </ul>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#toolbar -->

    <header id="branding" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <div id="sticky_navigation">
            <div class="container_16">
                <hgroup class="fleft grid_5">
                        <h1 id="site-title">
                            <a href="<?php echo  esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display'  ) ); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" rel="home">
                        <?php
                        if ( ot_get_option('wpl_logo') != ''){?>
                                <img src="<?php     echo ot_get_option('wpl_logo'); ?>">
                            <?php } else {
                                bloginfo('name');
                            }?>
                        </a></h1>
                            <h2 id="site-description">    <?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h2>
                </hgroup>

                <nav role="navigation" class="site-navigation main-navigation grid_11" id="site-navigation">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu_class' => 'nav-menu',  'theme_location' => 'primary' )); ?>
                </nav>

                <!-- Mobile navigation -->

                <div class="grid_16 mob-nav"></div>

                <!-- .site-navigation .main-navigation -->
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- #masthead .site-header -->
```

Comment: Please don’t show _server-side_ code (PHP), when you want to discuss a _client-side_ issue. Post pure HTML example code, and preferable also a live example, jsfiddle.net or something.

Comment: take a look here : http://www.booksofvirtue.com/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you completely loaded the webpage, Because its working perfectly for me on IE6+ using the IE11 emulation